# What water generating technology would be required to create a planetary scale flood?

Tags: science-based, technology, water

Aqadatio is a planet which is completely flooded. This flood was generated by its own government to get out of debt (long story). The inhabitants of this planet are technologically advanced, more so than humans are currently, and so I was wondering if there is anyway that the government would be able to create water in order to flood the planet? Is there any technology currently available that could create a enough water for a flood of this magnitude? Or if there's not could you come up with a 'scientific' method that possibly could? For example by combing oxygen and hydrogen molecules and forming rain colouds? 7

{I understand that there would not be enough water stored on the planet origionally however is there a way for the water to be **created**?}

Comment: We're doing it now - melt the ice caps.

Comment: Flooding the whole planet like Earth is impossible, because there's just not enough water on the planet. It has to be an act of God.

Comment: Hi ray.chill, welcome to Worldbuilding.  Tim gave you a terrific answer and, if you had more rep, you could upvote it, as it deserves.  But please wait longer than 9 minutes to choose a "best answer."  You might go back and choose Tim's in a day or two but holding off encourages more people to answer.  And that's what you really want, right?  Several excellent answers to inspire you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If their planet was like our earth then no, there just isn't enough water. You could flood low lying areas but higher ones would always still be safe.

You would need their planet to be colder then ours, with less tectonic activity and a higher base amount of water. You would also want a land mass at each pole.

The reduced tectonic activity would cause a flatter world with fewer and lower mountains. The colder climate and increased water levels mean that the climate would be dominated by massive ice caps covering both poles.

The government then just needs to increase the planets temperature by moving it closer to the sun, using orbital mirrors, emitting large amounts of greenhouse gas, painting the snow black or any number of other similar methods.

The ice caps would then melt and cover the entire planet in water. Possibly enough to submerge it entirely if the mountains are low enough and the ice caps thick enough.

Comment: "The government then just needs to increase the planets temperature by moving it closer to the sun". If you have the raw power to move your planet closer to the sun, wouldn't it be easier to "just" haul a big chunk of spatial ice back on the planet?


Moreover, our ellipse make the earth/sun distance varies wildly over a year without much effect, seasons being created by earth inclined axis. I'm not sure the distance you would have to cover to actually raise the average temperature enough for it to matter.

Comment: @Nyakouai 1. You would increase gravity. 2. You'd need to be careful not to be underneath it when it came down. 3. You'd need to make sure it came down slowly! 4. You'd need to put it somewhere it would melt and that would take a _long_ time. .... but yes that would work if you found a big enough chunk somewhere, as suggested in McTrooper's answer.

Comment: Irk, here's me commenting again without reading the next answer. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

If the civilization of the planet has already developed an advanced spatial technology, I think the best way would be to change the orbit of a properly sized comet or frozen water ice asteroid and make it fall onto the planet surface. This way enough water could be provided to flood the planet.
The problem is that there is no way to make it safe land; probably the ice body would be parked in orbit around the planet and launched toward the planet "one piece a time", calculating the trajectory so that it doesn't deal any damage to inhabited zones (think the catapult of Heinlein's "The Moon is a harsh mistress").
The pieces of ice would vaporize in the atmosphere (providing moisture that will later fall as rain) or reach the surface where thay would meld on the impact

Comment: I think it would work better to locate your mass drivers on one of Jupiter's icy moons, then launch a stream of smallish chunks.  You could also use this to give Mars an ocean :-)